# Empty map generated while converting alphanumeric string to a map of numbers and strings

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

Following code snippet is design for divides an alphanumeric string to a map of numbers and strings which is coming as a response body parameter from RestAPI.

```
String alphaNumericStr = "1XXGTE_FUSION2XXBIR_STALIO3XXVTE_CORE";
String regex = "[^a-zA-Z0-9']+";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(alphaNumericStr);

Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    map.put(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)), matcher.group(2));
}
System.out.println(map);
```

Expected result is

```
{1=XXGTE_FUSION, 2=XXBIR_STALIO, 3=XXVTE_CORE}
```

But i am getting an empty map. Can any one help me with this please.

Comment: The problem is that you do not have a group in your regex.

Comment: Can the `XXGTE_FUSION`, `XXBIR_STALIO`, etc. contain digits?

Comment: @Wiktor No.The string is separating using numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should throw `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1` because you try to extract `matcher.group(1)` and `matcher.group(2)` but you don't have any of them in your regex.

Instead, you can use this regex : [`(\\d+)(\\D+)`](https://regex101.com/r/ZFxLlM/1) to match two groups the first one match one or more digit, the second match one or more non digit.

```
String alphaNumericStr = "1XXGTE_FUSION2XXBIR_STALIO3XXVTE_CORE";
String regex = "(\\d+)(\\D+)";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(alphaNumericStr);

Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    map.put(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)), matcher.group(2));
}
System.out.println(map);
```

If you are using Java 9+ you ca use :

```
Map<Integer, String> map = Pattern.compile(regex)
        .matcher(alphaNumericStr)
        .results()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                m -> Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)), m -> m.group(2)
        ));

System.out.println(map);
```

Outputs

```
{1=XXGTE_FUSION, 2=XXBIR_STALIO, 3=XXVTE_CORE}
```

---

Beside I smile that you read this post here : [Divide an alphanumeric string into a map of numbers and strings](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/193870/divide-an-alphanumeric-string-into-a-map-of-numbers-and-strings)

Comment: Thanks for the Java 9 way, I didn't knew that `Collectors.toMap` was added.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati the trick is in [`results()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) which return a `Stream<MatchResult>` ;)

Comment: You are welcome @Aravinda Meewalaarachchi if that help you accept the answer please and up vote it

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with regex. Your regular expression does not contain any groups and you are trying to extract them.

Just change the regex to the following.

```
String regex = "(\\d)([a-zA-Z_]+)";
```

The first group here, `(\\d)` will match an integer number. The second group `[a-zA-Z_]+` will match any char sequence formed by a combination of alphabets and _.

```
String alphaNumericStr = "1XXGTE_FUSION2XXBIR_STALIO3XXVTE_CORE";
String regex = "(\\d)([a-zA-Z_]+)";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(alphaNumericStr);

Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();

while (matcher.find()) {
    map.put(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)), matcher.group(2));
}

System.out.println(map);
```

That will now solve this.

https://ideone.com/gZOhza

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can use two split calls to achieve the same thing (avoiding the regex API altogether):

```
String text = "1XXGTE_FUSION2XXBIR_STALIO3XXVTE_CORE";

String[] keys   = text.split("\\D+");
String[] values = text.split("\\d+");

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    map.put(keys[i], values[i + 1]); // +1 to skip the first blank
}

System.out.println(map);
```

Which prints:

```
{1=XXGTE_FUSION, 2=XXBIR_STALIO, 3=XXVTE_CORE}
```

Comment: Doesn't `text.split` use a `regex`? :)

Comment: @notyou It takes a regex, but this code doesn't use the regex API (`Matcher`, `Pattern`, etc.), it uses methods in the `String` class.

Comment: Ah I know, my comment was in jest.